Intellij IDEA clone failed
Cloning stops. I get the following error. I downloaded git to my computer, before that I downloaded git on Intellij IDEA and added plugins. Is there a solution to this error?
invalid path 'stockTracking /src/main/java/com/project/stockTracking/StockTrackingApplication.java' unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

I installed "git" on the computer but it didn't work. I have space on my disk.

Did you try this ? what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD

I think there is an issue with the file path in the repository you are trying to clone. First, check the repo to ensure that the file path is correct and doesn't contain any invalid characters or spaces, there is an extra space at the end of directory name 'stockTracking' as far as i can see. If it doesn't help, I recommend you to update the path in the repo. The error you faced can be due to case sensitivity as well. To update, if you have access to Linux system, try cloning the repo there. Linux system may handle the path better. Then, rename the directory and push the changes. The last thing i can say if none of those above works is that, if you are a Windows user, use Git Bash instead of cmd or Powershell to handle paths in a more graceful way let's say.Go to the directory where you want to clone the repo and right-click on it, then select Git Bash here. Try to clone the repo again with 'git clone'.
